# Rxjava - hot observables

Tags: rx-java

I am having a weird issue in RxJava when the producer (API request) is emitting the event too fast and the consumer (API response) only gets the second response of the API request.

Let's say I have a couple of requests that need to send to the server to query the database, because some of the queries from the server takes some time. So when I get the response, it might be possible that the second request returns first, and the weird thing is that sometimes I don't get the response of first request.

The code which makes an api call:

```
public void sendRequests() {
     // using RxJava to make server polling.
     startPollingServer();
}
```

The startPollingServer() method is to use RxJava to poll data from server.

```
public void startPollingServer() {
     mApiService.getPollingFromServer()
        .retryWhen()
        .repeatWhen()
        .map()
        .subscribeOn()
        .observeOn()
        .subscribe(
           // call onNext
           // call onError
         )
}
```

However, when sendRequests() is calling too fast, neither of onNext, onComplete, onError is called. Nothing is happened for first request.
But I do get the first response from CharlesProxy, which is really weird.

So my question would be, is it possible that RxJava just ignore my first response? Do I need to merge Observables that comes from startPollingServer()?

Comment: Do you use it in an Android application or in a test? Because if its a test, it will just fall through, because calling thread will subscribe and just go through the method startPollingServer. It is not recommanded to just subscribe in a void method. You will get memory leaks if you do not dispose the subscription. Your startPolling method should return Observable<> and compose in one place.

Comment: I am using in an android application, sendRequests() is initiated by user, I am simulating if user is hitting button or some UI very fast. It just shows some code snippet, i have the code to deal with subscribe the Subscription when application is destroyed, so no memory leak

Comment: why are you sure it is RxJava problem, does the server indeed return response in each case? seems you have here independent streams of Observables.

Answer (score 1):

According to my 2+ years of experience with RxJava it's very less likely it loses some data.
Consider following things:

**Error is suppressed**

Using retryWhen and repeatWhen may lead to an error suppression, try adding 'onError()' operator to catch those:

```
public void startPollingServer() {
     mApiService.getPollingFromServer()
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Got an error", throwable)) // catch error
        .retryWhen()
        .repeatWhen()
        .map()
        .subscribeOn()
        .observeOn()
        .subscribe(
           // call onNext
           // call onError
         )
}
```

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnError(rx.functions.Action1)

**Incorrect parallelism**

```
Observable.just(1,2,3)
.flatMap(i -> doNetworkCall(i))
.first()
```

such code may result parallel execution of 'doNetworkCall(i)' where second answer may come faster than first. To validate, use 'concatMap' instead, which guarantees and order of stream being processed: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html

**Debugging**

Operators 'doOnNext()', 'doOnSubscribe()', 'doOnCompleted()' and 'doOnError()' may help you to find an error

```
Observable.just(1,2,3)
.flatMap(i -> doNetworkCall(i)
          .doOnSubscribe(() -> log.debug("Launched {}", i))
          .doOnNext(response -> log.debug("Got response {} for {}", response, i))
          .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("For error for " + i, throwable))
          .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("Finished processing of {}", i))
)
.first()
```